# How do i check the name and see what number in the table it is corresponding two

Tags: lua

```
vars = {}
values = {}

function open(file)
    lex(file)
end

function lex(file)
    local data = io.open(file, "r")
    local value1 = 0
    local value2 = 0
    for char in data:lines() do
        --Print
        if char:sub(1, 6) == "print:" then
            print(char:sub(7))
        end
        --Integer
        if char:sub(1, 2) == "V:" then
            vars [#vars + 1] = char:sub(3, 5)
            if char:sub(6, 6) == "=" then
                values [#values + 1] = char:sub(7)
            end
            --print("NAME:"..vars [#vars]..", ".."VALUE:"..values [#values])
        end
        --Add
        if char:sub(1, 4) == "add:" then
            if char:sub(5, 7) == vars[1] then
                value1 = values[1]
            end
            if char:sub(9, 11) == vars[2] then
                value2 = values[2]
            end
            print(value1 + value2)
        end
    end
    --Debug purposes
    --[[
    for k, v in pairs(vars) do
        print(k, v)
    end
    for b, a in pairs(values) do
        print(b, a)
    end
    --]]
    print("VARS"..vars[1]..","..vars[2])
end

function run()
    while true do
        print("Open a file")
        file = io.read()
        print("File name:"..file)
        print("")
        lex(file)
        print("")
    end
end

run()
```

> Basically I want the add command two check the name and see what the corresponding number would be then set the value to the same number as the variable name value so I don't have to manually add "if char:sub(5, 7) == vars[1] then value1 = vars[1] end, etc."

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate to me. Looks like the next step in the process. However this also seems like the entirely wrong approach here as running tables is just asking for problems where a single table mapping variable to value avoids all of them and greatly simplifies the code/concept.

Comment: That, and the constant use of `char:sub(#,#)`, which should really just be `char:match`. I think this whole code could be cleaned up. He didn't add the code I suggested to him on the last one, either.

Comment: Yeah me and a lot of my friends are working on this and that was there way of writing the code so I went with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. This is your entire lex function rewritten. I haven't verified it working, and I'm not sure exactly which data you're trying to pull with the `print` before the last `end`, but this is should help you out.

```
function lex(file)
    local data = io.open(file, "r")
    local vars = {}
    for char in data:lines() do
        --Print
        if char:match("^print:") then
            print(char:match("^print: (.+)"))

        --Integer
        elseif char:match("^V:") then
            local k, v = char:match("^V: (.+)=(%d+)")
            vars[k] = v

        --Add
        elseif char:match("^add:") then
            local one, two = char:match("^add: (.+),(.+)")
            if not vars[one] or not vars[two] then
                print("At least one value is missing. Check for " .. one .. " and " .. two .. " in file.")
            else
                print(vars[one] + vars[two])
            end
        end
    end
end
```

You'll notice I added a check just on the off-chance that the file is missing a value somewhere.

Comment: This totally cleaned the code up a lot Danke